# WKWebView displays content wrong after orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am fairly new to iOS development and I'm using a `WKWebView` to display a page that plays a video using the Vimeo Player. When the app starts up, it shows the view correctly, no matter what orientation it is currently in. However, once I change the orientation the view will either look zoomed in or has whitespace below the video.

The annoying thing about this is that it's not consistent. Sometimes the view displays correctly, sometimes it doesn't. If I try to zoom the view in or out or try to scroll when using the app it usually corrects itself, but even that does not seem to be 100% reliable.

Some screenshots (tested on iPad 2):

Landscape orientation (correct):
[image: Landscape orientation (correct)]

Portrait orientation (correct):
[image: Portrait orientation (correct)]

Landscape orientation (incorrect):
[image: Landscape orientation (incorrect)]

Portrait orientation (incorrect):
[image: Portrait orientation (incorrect)]

And the code used to produce this result:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

class VideoViewController : UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {

@IBOutlet var containerView : UIView! = nil
var webView: WKWebView?

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    self.webView = WKWebView()
    let contentController = WKUserContentController();
    let scaleToFit = WKUserScript(source: "var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);", injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    contentController.addUserScript(scaleToFit)
    contentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "callbackHandler")
    self.view = webView!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    refreshUI()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func refreshUI() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://photofactsacademy.nl/api/vp.asp?id=152839850")
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webView!.loadRequest(requestObj)
}

func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if(message.name == "callbackHandler") {
        print("JavaScript is sending a message \(message.body)")
    }
}
}
```

I looked through SO for WKWebView and orientation change and didn't find anything that helped me.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe set the frames on rotation of device:

override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
//set frames for webview???
}

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I end up with the same results.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Your solution does work. Albeit there's a slight delay between the JavaScript call gets called and executed. Guess we'll have to live with it.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 21):

Can you try this

```
wkWebView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

Comment: I was running into this issue as well but for objective-c. Add   self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  self.webView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this problem by injecting a javascript reload call like this:

Swift:

```
 func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil, completion: {
     //Reset Frame of Webview
     webView.evaluateJavaScript("location.reload();", completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Objective C:

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    //Reset Frame of Webview
    [_webView evaluateJavaScript:@"location.reload();" completionHandler:^(id _Nullable obj, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"error:%@", error);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Updated to include both, hope that is ok.

Comment: This reloads the entire page...say if you have navigated to a deeper link...calling this will take you the base link....

Comment: I've combined this answer with the one from Abdul Yasin down below https://stackoverflow.com/a/57164217/1244883 and it worked like a charm. Essentially call `webView.reloadInputViews` inside `viewWillTransitionToSize`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to reload the entire web page. You just need to reload its input views. Make sure you have set constraints to web view properly and then add below code while changing orientation.

```
   // Reload inputs so that webview can adjust its content according to orientation
     [self.webView reloadInputViews];
```

Comment: please see @andre comment below.  Essentially call webView.reloadInputViews inside viewWillTransitionToSize

Answer (score 1):

After few hours of struggling, this is what worked for me:

```
<header><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no'></header><body style='margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width:100%; height:100%;'>...
```

Set width and height of both body and your video element to 100% and disable user scaling through header tag.

Comment: Not so a good idea for any website ... Only works if you have one website you control.

Comment: Well, I haven't tested this, but - you can feed in a custom html to your webview, while also having an iframe in body which will load any website. Maybe the problem is solved that way as well.

Comment: This would be a workaround, but the best thing is to let the website itself choose it's settings.