# Resizing Youtube iFrame while switching iOS device to landscape

Tags: ios, swift, iframe, youtube, landscape

I'm using UIWebView to play YouTube video. It works fine in portrait mode. While I switch to landscape mode, Youtube iFrame doesn't resize as UIWebView adapt constraints. Is there any way I can change Youtube iFrame for landscape mode ?

Comment: `UIWebView` is deprecated. Use `WKWebView` instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042412/wkwebview-displays-content-wrong-after-orientation-change

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {

    @IBOutlet weak var player: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         //palyYoutubePlayer()
        player.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "jsHandler")
        let bundleURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.absoluteURL
        let html = bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("try.html")
        player.loadFileURL(html, allowingReadAccessTo:bundleURL)
    }

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "jsHandler" {
            print(message.body)
            guard  let event = message.body as? NSString else {
                return
            }
            let str = String(event)
            if str == "reload" {
                self.player.reloadInputViews()
            }
        }
    }
}
```