# iOS wkwebview not showing mobile view of the website

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

iOS wkwebview always showing desktop view of the bootstrap website. Tried many ways, but nothing works. I want to have mobile view.

Answer (score 1):

What version of iOS are you using?

We used to set the view like this:

> `// User Agent
>   webview.customUserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (iPod; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; ja-jp) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5"`

Answer (score 0):

I got the fix from [WKWebView displays content wrong after orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042412/wkwebview-displays-content-wrong-after-orientation-change/42949994#42949994)

wkWebView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]